# Graphics Error in Adventure Capitalist the game

Tags: drivers, graphics, games, steam, opengl

Please check the steam discussion
**(i have posted this problem first in steam,the link :http://steamcommunity.com/app/346900/discussions/0/1458455461499157258/)**

IN STEAM

- Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
- Memory: 4 GB
- Processor: Pentium(R) Dual-Core CPU E5700 @ 3.00GHz × 2
- Graphics: Intel® G41
- OpenGL string: 2.1 Mesa 12.0.6
- OS type: 64-bit

I know that my GPU/driver may not meet the minimum requirements (OpenGL 3.2)
so I am using

`-force-opengl`

to run the game, and when I started it I found the graphics very glitchy.

Some images from what happened (please focus in the pictures):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0N7AM.jpg

The game was running well in windows but when I arrived to Linux I got this problem.

But I have other game in steam called (Time Clickers) and I run it without `-force-opengl` but there's the same problem.

Comment: Steam shows no special requirements for this game. Perhaps you should run it without force-opengl? On a side note, capitalism depletes resources pretty fast anywhere. Lots of regulatory patches may keep it in line for awhile but ultimately only the Socialism upgrade solves it.

Comment: MichaelBay iam using -force-opengl because of my openglversion,when i open the game without -force-opengl it opens then closes immediately and i searched on web for the problem and i found that in .config/unity3d/Hyper Hippo Productions Ltd./adCap!/player.log :                                            Failed to set up master OpenGL context (OpenGL Core (any supported profile)).
Your GPU/driver may not meet the minimum requirements ( <OpenGL 3.2>) the game reqires opengl 3.2 but my opengl version is 2.1

Answer (score -1, accepted):

UPDATED : thank you for all your work but the problem wasn't in unity but in my graphics card drivers and i had asked in intel community and i fond that i can download linux graphics from 01.org but there's a new problem in the software installation, if yu want to check it click in the link : https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2369312&p=13678612#post13678612